# Why force constexpr have compile time error only?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I'm watching [CppCon 2015: Scott Schurr “constexpr: Applications"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qO-9yiAOQqc), on [19'28"](https://youtu.be/qO-9yiAOQqc?t=19m28s) he's showing a trick to force compile time error only:

> A Way to Force Compile-Time Only?
>
> - Not within the standard
> - But a hack that sometimes works
>
> Unresolved Symbol In Throw
>
> ```
> extern const char* compile11_bin_invoked_at_runtime;
> template <typename T = std::uint32_t>
> constexpr T compile11_bin(
>   constexpr_txt t,
>   std::size_t i = 0, // index
>   std::size_t b = 0, // bit count
>   T x = 0) // accumulator
> {
>   return
>     i >= t.size() ? x : // end recursion
>     b >= std::numeric_limits<T>::digits ?
>     throw std::overflow_error("Too many bits!") :
>     t[i] == ',' ? compile11_bin<T>(t, i+1, b, x) :
>     t[i] == '0' ? compile11_bin<T>(t, i+1, b+1, (x*2)+0) :
>     t[i] == '1' ? compile11_bin<T>(t, i+1, b+1, (x*2)+1) :
>     throw std::domain_error( // Only '0', '1', and ','
>     compile11_bin_invoked_at_runtime);
> }
> ```

I'm curious here, what's the motivation to force a constexpr to have compile time error only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile time errors are *always* better than runtime errors.

Why? Because compile time errors can be fixed without running the application, and can thus be easily fixed. By throwing an unresolved external symbol, you can force the result of `compile11_bin` to be stored in a constexpr variable, which enables you to detect errors more quickly.

The example from the slide is:

```
constexpr auto maskA = constexpr11_bin<std::uint8_t>("1110 0000");
auto maskB = constexpr11_bin<std::uint8_t>("0001 1111");
```

Here, `maskA` results in a compile time error, which can be easily fixed. `maskB` on the other hand results in a runtime error, as `maskB` is not constexpr, and so the result doesn't have to be evaluated at compile-time, and you'll get a runtime error.

That's because `compile11_bin_invoked_at_runtime` is an unresolved external symbol, and every symbol has to have a definition, and so you get an error *at compile-time*, even if it's not the compiler *per se* that complains.